# Child Pages not Found 404 - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

In my wordpress I am trying to create a child page, but when I go to the page it's giving me an error 404 page not found.

I've tested the page and removed it as a child page and it works instantly.
I put it back under a parent and tried to update permalinks settings and flushing cache but still not found page.

This only happens with child pages, which makes me think its something wrong with the permalink structure, but not exactly sure what is wrong with it.

I will continue using unchilded pages for now, but would be great to get this bug solved. Any help is greatly appreciated.

below is the .htaccess file which is surprisingly long.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /beta2/
    RewriteRule ^/beta2/http:/kuzcolighting.com/beta/wp-content/hostinger-page-cache/ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(wordpress_test_cookie|comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle|wp_woocommerce_session_) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/beta2/http:/kuzcolighting.com/beta/wp-content/hostinger-page-cache/$1/_index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta2/http:/kuzcolighting.com/beta/wp-content/hostinger-page-cache/$1/_index.html [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 weeks"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /beta2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Use PHP7.1 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php71/lib
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not a bug.  Its an issue with your permalinks.  Is your htaccess file getting written? (WP shows you a notice / warning when you save permalinks if it is unable to write your htaccess file).  Include the contents of your htaccess here.

Comment: I've added the .htaccess in the original post. Currently I see a couple rewrite rules with http://kuzcolighting.com/beta2 which is the old domain. Now it is on http://kuzcolighting.com/beta. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If permalink flush cache didn't slove your problem. In most cases this solution fixes the WordPress posts 404 error. However, if it does not work for you, then you probably need to update your .htaccess file manually.

Add this code in your .htaccess file:

    
    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`